# How to replace specific character such as bracket in php

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying for the past three days to replace a bracket within my own delimiter. Something like

```
(  ( [take] function ( [/take] (
```

To look like

```
[take] function [ [/take]
```

Without affecting brackets outside of the `[take][/take]` delimiters

I have tried

```
preg_replace('/[^\[take\]]([)[^\[\take\]]/', '[', $string);
```

Comment: Replacing `( ( function () (` by `[]` would look like `[ [ function [] [`. Can you explain more clearly what you wanted?

Comment: I just want the change any opening square bracket in the [take] [/take] delimiters. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a regular expression:

```
$string = "( ( [take] function( [/take] (";
$result = preg_replace_callback(
    "/(\[take\])(.*?)(\[\/take\])/",
    function($m) {return $m[1] . str_replace("(", "[", $m[2]) . $m[3];},
    $string
);
echo $result;
```

[`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) allows you to execute a callback function on the match. In this case we use matching groups (within parentheses) to isolate the text between the tags, and then in the callback replace the parenthesis with a bracket.

Answer (score 0):

if the spacing is consistent then:

```
$result = str_replace('function ()', 'function []', '( ( function () (');
```

Comment: Thanks, I wrongly typed the question. It has been edited now. I appreciate your reply.